# can't calculate tangents because mesh doesn't contain normals

Tags: unity3d, blender

Пытаюсь импортировать модельку из блендера в юнити, пропадает часть модельки и выдает варнинги can't calculate tangents because mesh doesn't contain normals, как исправить данную ошибку?
В блендере буквально второй день, не ругайтесь сильно

[image: В блендере]
[image: В юнити]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Blender` тут вообще не причем. Хоть 2ой день, хоть 0ой, это модель, из чего она состоит, разработчику в отличие от художника, нужно знать обязательно.

<strike>Части</strike> полигоны модельки не пропадают, а тупо **направлены не в ту сторону!** За это отвечает направление нормалей, `normals` о которых говорится в ошибке. 3D редакторы в отличие от игровых движков могут себе позволить не экономить и отображать, как лицевую, так и тыльную сторону полигона.

Направление `face` можно отобразить параметром `Face Orientation`:

[image: Face Orientation]

- Пересчитать нормали автоматически: <kbd>Mesh</kbd> ‣ <kbd>Normals</kbd> ‣ <kbd>Recalculate Outside</kbd>
- Повернуть нормали в ручную: <kbd>Mesh</kbd> ‣ <kbd>Normals</kbd> ‣ <kbd>Flip</kbd>

---

Моделька кстате не для игры, без повода, полигонами насрано как не в себя. Одни только цилиндры заберут пол бюджета полигонов мобильника.